# Validation MSE loss is different from validation MSE metric

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have written a model in Keras (with theano backend) and compile my model like this:

```
model.compile(Adam(0.001), loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
```

i.e. my objective loss function is *mean squared error* and the metrics to report are *mean squared error* and *mean absolute error*.

Then I run my model:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=500, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Keras reports results as:

```
> Epoch 500/500:
0s - loss: 5.5990 - mean_squared_error: 4.4311 - mean_absolute_error: 0.9511 - val_loss: 7.5573 - val_mean_squared_error: 6.3877 - val_mean_absolute_error: 1.1335
```

I expected `val_loss` to be same as `val_mean_squared_error`. What is `val_loss` here if not `val_mean_squared_error`?

Comment: I would expect the same thing. That is some strange behavior. 
I am facing a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938176/why-differ-metrics-calculated-by-model-evaluate-from-tracked-metrics-during-tr). 
It seems, there is some trouble at calculating metrics in Keras...

Comment: Are you using any regularization layers? Their penalties add up to final loss.

Comment: could you share your network configuration as well? it will make things clearer

Comment: This seems to be the same issue (bug) as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802328/why-am-i-getting-different-values-between-loss-functions-and-metrics-in-tensorfl